# Scala: type mismatch

Tags: scala

I spend awful amount of time to figure it out following:

rmseList is a List of doubles

```
val rmseList = List(Double)

var tempRMSE : Double = 0.0;
for(rmse <- rmseList) {
  val idx = rmseList.indexOf(rmse) + 1
  tempRMSE = rmse
}
```

I get following error, when I am trying to iterate list and assign current value to temp variable.

```
[error]  found   : Double.type
[error]  required: Double
[error]       tempRMSE = rmse
```

Comment: What is `rmseList`?

Comment: Isn't this practically the same as `rmseList.last`? That loop makes no sense as written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably put the companion object for `Double` into a list instead of actually putting doubles there.  Here's an example:

```
scala> val xs = List(Double)
xs: List[Double.type] = List(object scala.Double)

scala> var d: Double = 0
d: Double = 0.0

scala> for (x <- xs) { d = x }
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double.type
 required: Double
              for (x <- xs) { d = x }
```

As to *how* you managed to put the companion object in instead of `Double` values, I don't know, because you didn't show us how you built the list.  Maybe somehow using parens `(Double)` instead of brackets `[Double]` to specify the type?